# If you were to add 5 images to your HTML file using <img>, how many extra HTTP GET calls will it result in?

Tags: http

If you were to add 5 images to your HTML file using `<img>`, how many extra HTTP GET calls will it result in?

Comment: Most likely zero, since most servers use the HTTPS protocol nowadays. You'll have one HTTP GET per URL that references an http resource (i.e. starting with `http:`).

Comment: @kuroineko HTTPS is an extension of HTTP which adds encryption, but doesn't change request-response mechanism in any way relevant to this question.

Comment: Well, nothing worth starting a war about. Technically HTTPS is defined in RFC 2828 as HTTP/TLS, I don't know if that counts as a separate protocol. Let's say the question was a bit vague.

Answer (score 2):

That depends. In its simplest, if each `<img>` specifies different `src` and your user agent (browser most typically) loads them for the first time, **5** requests would be fired for the 5 `<img>`s.

If you loaded them already once, they got cached on the client (if the caching policy allows it and the cached assets didn't expire), they can be retrieved from the cache **without firing a request** to the server.

I can also imagine a situation where all those `<img>` load the same 1 resource (so that you can eg. use it the same way as CSS sprite or you just want to display the same image multiple times) in which case only **1 request** would be fired from a user agent to save client's and server's resources.

To make this more complicated, you can have some clever loading policies in place like Cloudflare's [Mirage](https://blog.cloudflare.com/introducing-mirage-intelligent-image-loading/) which loads first a low quality version of an image to load it fast and immediately starts downloading the high quality version, which would result in **10 requests** fired. But Mirage can also delay loading of those images which are far from being displayed in the client's viewport so that would initially result in **fewer requests fired** depending on where the images occur on your page.